# On the lifting property of canonical map between inner Hom

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

This question arises from the lecture notes.
The notation $\perp$ means the thing on the left has the left lifting property w.r.t the thing on the right and, at the same time the right has right lifting property w.r.t the left.
For $u:A\to B,v:C\to D$ monomorphisms in $sSet$. And $p:X\to Y$ a morphism in $sSet$. Why do we have such equivalences between the following:
(1) $(A\times D\cup B\times C\hookrightarrow B\times D) \perp (p:X\to Y)$
(2) $(A\to B)\perp (\underline{Hom}(D,X)\to\underline{Hom}(D,Y)\times_{\underline{Hom}(C,Y)}\underline{Hom}(C,X))$
(3) $(C\to D)\perp (\underline{Hom}(B,X)\to\underline{Hom}(B,Y)\times_{\underline{Hom}(A,Y)}\underline{Hom}(A,X))$
Notation:

1. $A\times D\cup B\times C$ is defined by $A\times D\cup_{A\times C} B\times C$.\
2. $\underline{Hom}(A,Y)_n=Hom_{sSet}(A\times\Delta^n,Y)$\

My progress: I know that there is an adjunction
$$Hom_{sSet}(X,\underline{Hom}(Y,Z)\cong Hom_{sSet}(X\times Y,Z)$$
But I struggle to see how it is applied to the colimit and limit such that the diagram is kinda rotated.

Comment: This is a consequence of the adjunction between product and hom. It's best to draw the diagrams and use the adjunction property to transform them into each other.

Comment: Yes indeed. But I struggled to see how the adjunction is applied to the product. Would you give some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is completely elementary, but it takes a long time to dot all the $i$'s: https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06074

Comment: Thank you. The paper now looks kinda advanced for me now but I will check it out when I understand more.

Comment: Feel free to ask for clarification; I don't exclude the possibility something can be written more clearly, but at some point I just got tired...